# regex - match a word so long as it isn't in quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say for example I have a string like the one below

```
the car is made of cardboard 'the car in mud' bla bla car bla car 'bla bla car bla' blaa
```

In this string I am trying to match the word 'car', but only if it's not inside quotation marks and and the word is on its own, so 'cardboard' doesn't count.

As you can see, in this particular string there are 2 sets of quotation marks: `'the car in mud'` and `'bla bla car bla'`; I don't want car to be matched in these locations.

My first thought was to use lookaheads and lookbehinds to make sure that there were not a proceeding and following quotation marks, but this fails in this section:

```
'the car in mud' bla bla car bla car 'bla bla car bla'
```

...where if you look behind you see a quotation mark and you looking ahead you see one too, but it's actually the closing one for the previous and the opening for the next, but it's not actually a part of quotation marks?

I can use the following to capture all quotation mark sections, but how can I incorporate this with finding the word that lies outside of them?

```
('|")[^'"]*('|")
```

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript? Python?

Comment: Are you replacing? Extracting?

Comment: javascript, and just trying to match all in the string, then replace with something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways of doing this, but this seems to work...

```
var input="the car is made of cardboard 'the car in mud' bla bla car bla car \"bla bla car bla\" blaa"

var exp = new RegExp("((?<=[^\\.\\w]|^)car(?!\\w))|(('|\")[^'\"]*('|\"))", "g");

inp=input.replace(exp, function(el){
                  if(el[0]==="'" || el[0]==="\""){ return el }
                  return "dog"
                  });
```

instead of checking for the quotation mark in the match could i use some kind of regex grouping instead to check for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
((['\"])(?:(?!\2).)*)\bcar\b((?:(?!\2).)*\2)
```

The only downfall is that if `car` is found twice within the quotes then it only captures the last one.

https://regex101.com/r/TscK3w/1

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your output needs to look, the easiest thing might be to *take out* the parts you don't want to match by doing something like this:

```
const exp = /'.+?'/g
var txt = "the car is made of cardboard 'the car in mud' bla bla car bla car 'bla bla car bla' blaa";
var new_text = txt.replace(exp, " ");
console.log(new_text);
```

This expression just looks for quotation mark and then any character except newlines until the next quotation mark. I stress that this solution's usefulness depends on what you need the output to be. However, if you need to separate the pre and post quote-blocks into rows, you could replace them with a unique delimiter, such as $$$$$ and then use that as your splitting token.

**UPDATE:** Based on your edit, my solution would work if you remove all the quote blocks and then do a simple search for your term. All resulting matches would have to be outside any quote blocks.